# Remove from "Wordpress" when reciving email (Should I remove filter?)

Tags: wp-mail

I am getting "Wordpress" when I sending my email using wp_mail. So to remove "Wordpress" from my e-mail I am using filter like so:

```
//Remove "Wordpress" when receiving email 
function remove_from_wordpress($email){
$wpfrom = get_option('blogname');
return $wpfrom;
}

add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'remove_from_wordpress');
```

It works great and now I am getting site name instead.
 My question: Is this a proper way to do it? Because I am concerned that my filter will maybe break some other plugins. If that is the case how can I avoid that? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [`wp_mail_from_name`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_from_name) filter is a correct way to change the "From" name in emails sent by WordPress. It should not cause any issues with other plugins.